# TinyBrowser / TinyMCE PHP, not working after flash was removed from browsers

Tags: php, tinymce

To all who are forced to work on legacy websites that use the tinybrowser plugin for tinyMCE

First of all, get rid of it, if not possible to remove for whatever reason you can use following fix to replace flash based upload for HTML form

Find file upload.php it will be under tinymce plugins tinybrowser somewhere

to the head of the HTML that is on this file include jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To the container that used to be the flash content "" add following

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="Filedata" />
</form>
<input type="submit" id="submit_form" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit_form").click(function(){

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('Filedata', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                   url : "/js/tiny_mce/plugins/tinybrowser/upload_file.php?obfuscate=<?php echo md5($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$tinybrowser['obfuscate']); ?>&type=<?php echo $typenow; ?>&folder=<?php echo urlencode('/images/uploads'); ?>",
                   type : 'POST',
                   data : formData,
                   processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                   contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
                   success : function(data) {
                       if(data == "<html><head><title>File Upload Success</title></head><body>File Upload Success</body></html>") {

                            location.replace("/js/tiny_mce/plugins/tinybrowser/upload_process.php?filetotal=1&obfuscate=<?php echo md5($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$tinybrowser['obfuscate']); ?>&type=<?php echo $typenow; ?>&folder=<?php echo urlencode('/images/uploads/'); ?>");

                            /*
                            $.post("/js/tiny_mce/plugins/tinybrowser/upload_process.php?filetotal=1&obfuscate=<?php echo md5($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$tinybrowser['obfuscate']); ?>&type=<?php echo $typenow; ?>&folder=<?php echo urlencode('/images/uploads/'); ?>", function(data, status){
                                location.replace("/js/tiny_mce/plugins/tinybrowser/tinybrowser.php?type=image&feid=choose_main_product_image");
                            });
                            */
                       }
                   }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can remove / PHP comment out the variables set for that div, they were meant to be used for the flash content

This should get single file upload going, despite you should consider removing the plugin, I do not trust it a bit

Comment: I had tinyMCE working without flash on all browsers ! I think it has nothing to do with flash, do you see any Javascripts error in the console when you're trying to use TinyMCE ?

Comment: Wait a second, is your "question" a copy/paste from a tutorial?

Comment: ok guys, tinybrowser plugin for TinyMCE uses flash to upload, this is where it goes wrong, since modern browsers do not use flash anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet has few issues, but can be used as a template to replace the deprecated Flash module with pure PHP. `upload_process.php` partial codebase can be migrated to `upload_file.php`. Here is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/akotulu/ad4ea148031a266e51fb32f0a9b71718) of changes.